# Using a <button type="submit">Save</button> does not fire consistenttly

Tags: html, forms, button

My application uses "button" html elements for submitting forms. The code is below...

```
<button class="button save" name="save" type="submit">Apply Changes</button>
```

However, I'm finding that sometimes I need to click the button a few times in order to get it to submit. Is this a known issue with the html button object?

Can I apply an onclick handler to insure the button fires consistently on first click?

Comment: From just that alone, I don't see why you would need multiple clicks. Care to post more code, particularly parts you think may be contributing to the issue? Perhaps the form, or let us know what the form action does, etc.

Comment: why not just use <input type='submit' name='save' class='button save' value='Apply Changes' /> if you are trying to save form data that's what the input type is for and you can style it.  If you just looking for a click even then drop and ID on the button and change the type to button and bind a click event to it

Comment: it should work, but I've had bad experiences when using particular names for things in some browsers (like IE).  Try changing class name from 'button' to something else, and maybe not using class and name be both 'save'.  A little superstitious but you'd be surprised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers will react differently to the `<button>` tag, especially Internet Explorer. If you are using this button for an HTML form, `<input type="submit">` is the way to go since it's fully supported by major browsers.

Both `<button>` and `<input>` tags can provide a rich content if CSS attributes are done correctly, despite what you read on the internet. I always go with `<input>`, it's safer.